# svg code HTML 5 path golden spiral

Tags: html, svg, kineticjs

i am looking to create a text animation along a spiral path
something on the lines of this http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-spiral-text/

my attempt is to make the path a golden spiral instead of the one in the above code. the svg code for the golden spiral is given below... i have tried replacing the path data, but only the first curve loads...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="1024px" height="768px" viewBox="0 0 1024 768" enable-background="new 0 0 1024 768" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="ARC">

    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.7087" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M32,87.344c0,327.678,265.635,593.313,593.313,593.313"/>
</g>
<g id="ARC_1_">

    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.7087" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M625.313,680.656C827.829,680.656,992,516.485,992,313.969"/>
</g>
<g id="ARC_2_">

    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.7087" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M992,313.969c0-125.162-101.464-226.625-226.625-226.625"/>
</g>
<g id="ARC_3_">

    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.7087" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M765.375,87.344c-77.354,0-140.063,62.708-140.063,140.062"/>
</g>
<g id="ARC_4_">

    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.7087" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M625.313,227.406c0,47.808,38.756,86.563,86.563,86.563"/>
</g>
<g id="ARC_5_">

    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.7087" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M711.876,313.969c29.546,0,53.499-23.953,53.499-53.5"/>
</g>
<g id="ARC_6_">

    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.7087" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M765.375,260.47c0-18.261-14.804-33.064-33.064-33.064"/>
</g>
<g id="ARC_7_">

    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.7087" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M732.311,227.406c-11.286,0-20.435,9.149-20.435,20.435"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply append the paths' `d` attribute and delete the rest of your arcs:

```
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.7087" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M32,87.344c0,327.678,265.635,593.313,593.313,593.313           
    M625.313,680.656C827.829,680.656,992,516.485,992,313.969 
    M992,313.969c0-125.162-101.464-226.625-226.625-226.625
    M765.375,87.344c-77.354,0-140.063,62.708-140.063,140.062
    M625.313,227.406c0,47.808,38.756,86.563,86.563,86.563
    M711.876,313.969c29.546,0,53.499-23.953,53.499-53.5
    M765.375,260.47c0-18.261-14.804-33.064-33.064-33.064
    M732.311,227.406c-11.286,0-20.435,9.149-20.435,20.435
"/>
```

Comment: hi duopixel, i have actually tried that, doesnt really work http://jsfiddle.net/textonym/bAESn/

Comment: Well, there's a couple of failure points. The first thing I'd try is implementing in pure SVG to see if the problem relies on the library (kinectjs), of course this is not a trivial task so it's not "something simple"

Comment: I'd also try using a path with absolute values (the path syntax should have uppercase `C`'s). But it's really a shot in the dark, you need to find the failure point through trial and error.

Comment: thanks for the tip... i had left it.. but will try again.. was just playing with kinetic. thanks for the help duopixel.